# nginx reverse proxy stop port override

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx currently to run two node apps on one vps. It's working however, from either URL, if I manually enter the port of the other it will run the other app, ie going to mydomain1.com and mydomain2.com correctly routes to node apps running on ports 1337 and 1338. However I can do mydomain1.com:1337 or mydomain1.com:1338 and I can access either app, this doesn't seem correct. Can I, and if so how, prevent appending the port to cross access apps?

Here are my files located in etc/nginx/conf.d, mydomain1.conf and mydomain2.conf:

mydomain1.conf

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mydomain1.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

mydomain2.conf

```
    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name mydomain2.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

I also added a /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file with the following contents:

```
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

Comment: this seems more of a firewall issue? The domain name just gets you to the machine, and if the node servers are running on 'exposed' ports, then of cause you can access them. You should probably lock down the exposed ports, and maybe enforce domain redirecting within the applications routes.

Comment: That sounds correct, plus plus, my networking skills could be better, move that to an answer and I can mark this as answered.

Comment: Web servers probably only need to expose ports 80 for http, 443 for https, 22 for ssh and maybe 25 for ftp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems more of a firewall issue? The domain name just gets you to the machine, and if the node servers are running on 'exposed' ports, then of cause you can access them. You should probably lock down the exposed ports, and maybe enforce domain redirecting within the applications routes.

Web servers probably only need to expose ports 80 for http, 443 for https, 22 for ssh and maybe 25 for ftp

Comment: maniacalrobot, take a look my supplemental answer to my own question below, do you think this is a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have noted, the best thing is to both set up a firewall *and* only bind your node application to listen on `localhost`.

---

For the firewall you don't *have* to mess with iptables, you can use [ufw](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) (**U**ncomplicated **F**ire**w**all). This makes securing a web server's ports pretty painless:

- Initially deny all incoming connections by default
- Only allow `HTTP:80`, `HTTPS:443`, `SSH:22` and `FTP:21`

For a debian/ubuntu system, that process looks like this (first ensuring you are `root` or `sudo`):

```
$ apt install ufw
$ ufw default deny incoming

$ ufw allow ssh
$ ufw allow http
$ ufw allow https
$ ufw allow ftp

$ ufw enable
```

If you type `ufw status` you can see what rules you have active.

---

For only binding your node process to localhost (so that anything that isn't on your server can't connect to that port), you can pass the hostname as the second parameter of the [`server.listen()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) (or `app.listen()` for [express](http://expressjs.com/)):

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;
const HOST = "localhost" || "127.0.0.1"; // You can use either of these

app.listen(PORT, HOST, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`Listening on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It was sensible to set up your firewall like this and it obviously provided a solution.

In case you are interested, the actual reason your node apps were accessible is that unless you bind them to an IP they are listening for traffic on all your network interfaces, so will respond to requests on your public IP.

Bind your node apps (or any server running on your machine) to 127.0.0.1 and it will only respond to internal requests, including those proxied by Nginx, but not the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer to my own question which I accepted an answer that got me going in the right direction. This answer might prove useful to someone hitting this thread down the line.

There are definitely more robust ways out there, but for me using linux iptables with the following allows only port 80 and port 22 (for my ssh sessions), and therefore the user cannot enter mydomain1:1337 or mydomain1:1338, it also includes a few basic attack protections:

flush

```
    iptables -F
```

block null packets

```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
```

syn-flood attack protection

```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

XMAS packets protection

```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
```

Allow local host

```
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
```

Now we can allow web server traffic:

```
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow related, established

```
    iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```